# Detect and convert encoding for list of files

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have a directory which contains both ISO-8859 and UTF8 encoded files. I want to convert all ISO files to UTF8 encoding, and leave the UTF8 files untouched. So far, I've got this:

```
for isoFile in `file exports/invoice/* | grep "ISO-8859"`; do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "$isoFile" -o "$isoFile"; done
```

The problem is that `file exports/invoice/* | grep "ISO-8859"` returns a list of files in this format:

```
exports/invoice/2014.03547.html:                 HTML document, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

which of course will not work for iconv. I need to extract the filename from this string and run it through iconv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to use awk:

`file exports/invoice/* | grep "ISO-8859" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For completeness' sake the whole command to convert the encoding becomes:
for file in `file exports/invoice/* | grep "ISO-8859" | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`; do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "$file" -o "${file}"; done

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the filename from this string using the following command:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 //to select first column

rev | cut -c 2- | rev //to remove ':' from the end of the name
```

**So the whole command to extract the filename gets this way:**

```
file exports/invoice/* | grep "ISO-8859" | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

And it will return to you: exports/invoice/2014.03547.html

Comment: Thx, I've preferred the awk method as suggested above, because it is shorter and also works with spaces in filenames.